# C++ Virtual keyword as a way to avoid including code units

Tags: c++, virtual, late-binding, dlopen

Currently we have a body of code that allows service plugins which offer forms of communication to the core e.g tcp/ip, udp/ip, usb, etc... These service plugins feedback notifier class instances to the core for further processing.

In the current implementation a service project (which is a separate dynamically linked library brought in at runtime by the core via dlopen and friends) will compile against the notifier.cpp file that resides in the core source code (a separate project). This gives access to the notifiers method implementations. This works perfectly no complaints.

Two alternative options:
1. put the notifier method implementations in the header file.
2. declare the notifier methods virtual and delay binding until runtime.

Avoiding the issues of computational overhead what are the impacts of option 2?

Are there any other options available to us?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to declare them `virtual` unless you intend to override them in derived classes?

Comment: Incidentally, another option is to have the method implementations compiled into the core, rather than the service.

Comment: The thinking is if the internal processing of a method changes, say a bug fix, we don't want to have to recompile every plugin to take advantage of this fix. If we had runtime binding it would take the version being run in the core, the one with the fix.... no?

Comment: @user394663: Then go with my suggestion above...

Comment: The service plugin refuses to build without the method implementation. Using the virtual keyword get around this. Note the core is not a library its a application which loads libraries on demand.  Thanks for your prompt replies btw.

Comment: @Oli: Introducing an interface to satisfy dependencies is a widely-used method of decoupling.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Right, but that doesn't seem to be what the OP's doing.  He/she seems to be literally just adding `virtual` to an existing class definition, not actually introducing a pure-virtual base class.

Comment: @Oli: I see what you mean.  However your comment "go with my suggestion above" isn't very clear...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, exposing an interface with pure virtual functions to consumers is the standard way of exposing C++ objects from a Windows DLL.  The client isn't aware of any implementation details: no member variables, no member function bodies, just virtual layout.

(Add reference counting and a language-agnostic version of `dynamic_cast`, which we'll call `QueryInterface`, and you have COM, which is pervasive on Windows)

This technique will work just fine on *nix shared libraries as well.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Ben. So perfectly legit to place the virtual keyword to get around errors such as the following  Undefined symbols: Notifier::get_name(), referenced from:      SQLiteDataSource::select_notifier(string const&, string const&, string const&) in SQLiteDataSource.o   This will stop this error in the SQLiteDataSource plugin and delay binding until runtime.

Comment: @user394663: Letting the client know about a base class with pure virtual functions, and then implementing them in a derived class is a very good way of decoupling (preventing the client from trying to use the implementation directly).  Simply sprinkling the code with `virtual` is not.  You have to introduce inheritance to correctly separate the interface from the implementation.